# How to filter images by using categories in django?

Tags: django, categories, imagefilter

I'm trying to make a gallery page for my Django application and I want to display images of specific category on their respective pages but the issue I face is I'm unable to apply filter for that like I have several images related to food and some related to travel I want to display all food images on a food page and all travel images on its travel page I have created a drop-down list of my all pages to display that image please have a look on this screenshot https://prnt.sc/qnznml !
I tried `def get_queryset(self):
        return Postgallery.objects.filter(postgallery_id=self.kwargs.get('slug'))`
but it does't work

Modeld.py

```
    class Page(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    overview = models.TextField(null=True)
    backgroung = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.heading
class Postgallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Title")
    overview = models.TextField(null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('gallery-detial', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Photos(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    page = models.ForeignKey(Postgallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Postgallery")
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    show = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Postgallery.objects.filter(postgallery_id=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: @sandeep Please check it!

Comment: Are you trying to filter Photos based on a slug of postgallery table ? If it is then, queryset would be like this.
Photos.objects.filter(page__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))

Comment: No, actually I want to filter my photos on the basis of Postgallery id!

Comment: Then you need to pass id in kwargs not slug and filter like this: Postgallery.objects.filter(postgallery_id=self.kwargs.get('id')). Slug and id are different fields